# how can I disable ubuntu system startup code display?

Tags: startup

how can I disable ubuntu system startup code display? Like the picture as follows:

[image]

Comment: Output of these would help: `cat /etc/default grub`, `dmesg`, `cat /var/log/boot.log`

Answer (score 2):

Open `/etc/default/grub`
and edit the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line like the following:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
```

Then `sudo update-grub` for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just check my Grub setting and also in Quiet model. This picture appears before login screen and I can see Ubuntu boot logo before this picture.

Comment: To my knowledge, once you set `quiet` you shouldn't be seeing any of these text. See this: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Silent_boot .. Did you edit and update grub as suggested?

Comment: Yes I'm agree with you. My Linux version is Ubuntu Gnome 15.10. My last version Ubuntu gnome 14.04 LTS looks don't have this problem.

Comment: And I have sudo update grub